# NSNotifications in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, beta, nsnotifications

Are the new notifications not currently working in Swift 3?

I am doing:

```
NotificationCenter.default().post(name: DidTouchParticleView, object: self.particle as? AnyObject)
```

In a custom view's `touchesBegan()` and I need to send the `particle` object to the view controller if there is one. So I do this:

```
NotificationCenter.default().addObserver(forName: DidTouchParticleView, 
                                         object: self,
                                         queue: OperationQueue.main(),
                                         using: presentParticleDisplayView(notification:))
```

In a view controller's `viewDidLoad()`. I am certain that that particular view controller is the one presented when I tap my custom view, however, the function `presentParticleDisplayView(notification:)` is never called.

Also, `DidTouchParticleView` is defined globally like this:

```
let DidTouchParticleView = NSNotification.Name("didTouchParticleView")
```

Is this due to the beta, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In the current beta, and in Swift 3 going forward, the parentheses after `default()` are removed; it is `NotificationCenter.default`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you may be intending to call `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)`, where the second parameter message (the `selector:`) is sent to the first parameter (the target).

Instead, you are calling the wrong method, `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)`, which works quite differently.

Also, as to the second part of your question:

```
let DidTouchParticleView = NSNotification.Name("didTouchParticleView")
```

That is correct (almost); it should be

```
let DidTouchParticleView = Notification.Name("didTouchParticleView")
```

All notification names are now `Notification.Name` instances. The proper way to do this is to say:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let didTouchParticleView = Notification.Name("didTouchParticleView")
}
```

You can then refer to the notification's name as `.didTouchParticleView` throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're watching for yourself to post the notification (`object: self`). You probably mean something like `object: particle` or possibly `object: nil` in the `addObserver` call (but then be careful to make sure it's the right particle in the handler). Re-read the docs for this method and note carefully what the `object` parameter is for.

Note that this version of `addObserver` returns an observer object. You must store that so you can later call `removeObserver` with it.

Comment: Changing `object` to nil solves it. However, how does it know what has become the observer? Before, in Swift 2, there used to be `addObserver:` that takes an object as the observer.

Comment: @YoussefSami No, you didn't understand what was going in before. The `object` was _never_ the observer. The observer is _returned_ from the call. Don't confuse this with `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)`, where the first parameter _is_ the observer. See now my edited answer.

Comment: @matt Yes, that's the one to which I was referring. So how does the Notification Center now know to which object to send the notification?

Comment: @YoussefSami It's the same as it always was. The first parameter is the target to which the selector will be sent. As I said, see my edited answer.