# Sharing information between ViewContollers

Tags: ios, swift3

I am developing a game using Sprite and the game works perfectly fine. I am trying to add in a feature that allows you to change things on that GameView. But the buttons for the feature are on a different ViewController. How would I be able to have the code be implemented into a different view controller?

This is the code i want the button to implement

```
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        // Get the location of the touch in this scene
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        // Check if the location of the touch is within the button's bounds
        if button.contains(location) {
            Ghost.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Ghost2")
        }
    }
```

And here is the button

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: AnyObject) {
```

}
But the button is on ViewController1 and the object that i want to change is on ViewController2 (GemScene)

Comment: you can use NSUserDefault (preference) to share info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this question:

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) (One of the answers shows Swift 3 syntax.)

Anyway, what I personally have done in these cases is to use [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter), which provides loosely coupled messages even between different ViewControllers. You can take a look here: [NSNotifications in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310080/nsnotifications-in-swift-3)