# NotificationCenter Crash in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, notificationcenter

Is it just me, or did `NotificationCenter` become a hot mess in Swift 3? :)

I have the following setup:

```
// Yonder.swift
extension Notification.Name {
  static let preferenceNotification = Notification.Name("preferencesChanged")
}

// I fire the notification elsewhere, like this:
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .preferenceNotification, object: nil)
```

In my first view controller, this works great:

```
// View Controller A <-- Success!
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshData), name: .preferenceNotification, object: nil)

func refreshData() {
  // ...
}
```

But this view controller:

```
//View Controller B <-- Crash :(
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadEntries(search:)), name: .preferenceNotification, object: nil)

func loadEntries(search:String?) {
  // ...
}
```

...crashes with:

> [NSConcreteNotification length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

As far as I can tell, my observer is set up correctly. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSNotifications in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310080/nsnotifications-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your issue is with your `loadEntries(search:)` method. It's not a valid signature. The selector used with Notification Center must either have no parameters or just one parameter. And if you have one parameter, that parameter will be the `Notification` object, not the notification name.

Your `loadEntries` needs to be:

```
func loadEntries(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    // Optional check of the name
    if notification.name == .preferenceNotification {
    }
}
```

And the selector would need to be:

```
#selector(loadEntries(_:)) // or #selector(loadEntries)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!